# Handle errors in RazorPages OnPost handler without side effects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

Suppose an `OnGet` handler *loads data used on the page*. Then if an error is encountered in a corresponding `OnPost()` handler, it cannot simply `return RedirectToPage()` but rather must reload that data somehow and `return Page()` so as not to lose the `ModelState`.

But `return Page()` has side effects:

1. it shows a URL like `www.example.com/Foo?handler=OnPostAddCustomer`, and
2. if the user presses refresh the browser shows the "do you want to repost?" error (because a PRG was not performed).

My hacky solution was to perform a PRG to avoid those problems, but pass the errors in `TempData` so I can recreate the `ModelState` in the `OnGet()` handler:

```cs
[BindProperty] public List<long> Ids { get; } = new List<long>();

// ...

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
{
  // maybe recreate ModelState from OnPost handler
  if (TempData["CustomModelState"] is string s) {
    var errors = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>>(s);
    if (errors != null) {
      foreach (var (Key, Errors) in errors) {
        foreach (var error in Errors) {
          ModelState.AddModelError(Key, error);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // normal get request...
  await LoadDataUsedOnPage();
  return Page();
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCreateCustomer()
{
  // normal error handling
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return Page();

  // custom error handling for empty list `Ids` (e.g. user must choose items from dropdown)
  if (!Ids.Any()) {
    ModelState.AddModelError(nameof(Ids), "Must choose at least one item.");
    var errors =
      ModelState
      .Where(x => x.Value != null)
      .Where(x => x.Value!.Errors.Any())
      .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Value!.Errors.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage));
    TempData["CustomModelState"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(errors);
    return RedirectToPage();      // will run OnGet() again and thus load data
  }

  // normal post request...
  await PersistData();
  return RedirectToPage();        // PRG
}
```

I've always avoided `TempData` as it seems dirty, but in this case I can't find a better way. (PS: I used `TempData["CustomModelState"]` instead of `TempData["ModelState"]` as it seems the latter was already used.)

What is the canonical way to solve this problem? Is there a built-in approach for this scenario?

Comment: The PRG pattern is exactly what `TempData` is for, so I’d say this seems fine. Maybe use a more specific key to avoid weird effects when users work in multiple tabs at the same time or something.

Comment: Why are you using a named handler method instead of a straightforward OnPost?

Comment: @BenderBoy Are you saying that internally `TempData` is used by the framework to pass data between handlers, e.g. when model state is invalid then repopulate page?

Comment: @MikeBrind Because I have other post handlers in that model too, so if I had used `OnPost()` I was wary someone would post an answer which wouldn't apply to my case.

Comment: You can add `"{handler?}"` to the `@page` directive which will result in the hander name being added as a segment in the URL instead of a query string value. As far as the warning about double form submission goes, that's how the browser works regardless of handler names. It's a reasonable warning because some users might not realise that refreshing will result in a POST request, but why anyone would want to refresh at that point is a bit of a mystery to me.

Comment: @MikeBrind Thanks. Those side effects notwithstanding, do you think the approach I've used (stuffing TempData with errors to be read later in OnGet) is a reasonable solution?

Comment: If you asking whether TempData is a suitable tool for the workaround you have devised, then the answer is yes. Personally, I don't see the actual problem in the first place. PRG is only intended be used for successful submissions to prevent accidental double submission. If there are validation errors, you _want_ someone to submit again - after they have corrected the errors.

Comment: @MikeBrind I suppose it's a style issue: I want a more spa-like experience which people have become accustomed to. My preference is to repopulate the page, show some errors, and let the user decide how to proceed - without mangling the url or affecting the refresh behaviour. The workaround seems to work well so far. I realise what you've proposed is the norm, so thanks for your valuable feedback.

Comment: If you want a more SPA-like experience, validate on the client and prevent the post happening if there are validation errors.

Comment: @MikeBrind Yes I've done that too. :-) The server validation is a failsafe.